# Unity scroll view, как получать компоненты из инспектора, только тех объектов которые находятся в зоне видимости viewpot?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, у меня на сцене есть scroll view, подскажите как можно получать компоненты из инспектора, только тех объектов которые находятся в зоне видимости viewpot?

Comment: Посчитать, какие находятся, какие нет. Размеры маски, контента и позицию скролла знаешь, осталось вспомнить уроки матана начальной школы.